# Pyspark inferSchema numbers that start with 0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark (Spark 2.1.1) to infer the schema of a csv file:

```
sc.read.csv('/some/file.csv', inferSchema=True)
```

Problem is the data has certain columns where the values are numerical starting with 0 and they need to be stored as string so that I don't lose the 0s.

```
|string_int| true_int|
|       001|      625|
|       321|      123|
```

`inferSchema` will interpret `string_int` as an integer and will truncate the 0s. Is there a way I can modify the logic so that if there is a numerical value that starts with a 0 it will infer those columns as string?

I know I can specify the schema on read, but the purpose of this code is to interpret the schema of the csv.

Comment: I do not think the feature you are asking for currently exists in spark.

Comment: you can read them as text without inferSchema and then later cast the desired columns to desired datatypes